# Mobile Test Workbench - Unable to play recorded test

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

I am using IBM Mobile Test Workbench for automated testing of an hybrid application. Application is built using IBM worklight 6.1.

I set up the workbench environment. Recorded few of test cases using an ios device(version 6.0). I was able to generate reports for them. It was going fine until I tested a page which has a drop down.

When I recorded that page(which has a drop down), workbench successfully recorded all the steps. But when i tried to playback on the device. It failed!

Here are the recorded steps:

- Click On Jquery select menu whose content is 'XYZ'
- Set Row to 3 in component 1 in PickerView
- Click item at position 2 in Table View

Errors I am getting while playing back this recorded test:

- Set Row to 3 in component 1 in PickerView - **Unable To Find an Object of type UIPickerView**
- Click item at position 2 in Table View - **Unable To Find an Object of type UITableView**

Comment: Don't you mean Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight? Not the same as Rational Test Workbench.

Comment: Thanks. Any help would be really appreciated on this.

Answer (score 1):

During the playback are you able to see the iOS native PickerView ? In other words, has the click on the JQuery Select menu been performed or not ? This would explain why the player is unable to find the PickerView.

---

After some investigations, I can tell you that this issue has been fixed in RTW 8.6.x that is expected to ship in an upcoming WorkLight 6.2.x fixpack.

Meanwhile you could apply the following workaround by editing your test:
- Choose 'Select' instead of 'Click' on JQuery Select menu element
- In Text parameter: enter the text content of the chosen option
- Comment/Disable the following native steps